# How to combine multiple proxies into one using Python? Similar to Scrapy/Crawlera

Tags: python, scrapy

I have multiple proxies that i want to use with multiple Scrapy spiders simultaneously while managing things like domain specific access patterns and bans.
I want to do the following:

```
                          > external proxy 1
my_app > my_proxy_daemon  > external proxy 2
                          > external proxy 3
```

This is essentially what Crawlera does.

Which Python software would be easiest to adapt to this task?
 - proxy server to accept requests
 - proxy client to relay requests
 - making it all non blocking